# Set individual xtick labels on seaborn Facetgrid

Tags: python, seaborn

In the example below a number of observations, X and Y, are made and indexed by 'subject' and 'group'.

I want to plot sorted values for all the X and Y observations in a `FacetGrid` with columns of the FacetGrid being the groups.

Now The FacetGrid assign the xtick labels for all subplots like the last subplot in the `FacetGrid`. This is wrong since each subject is only in one group. 
How do one make sure that it is the 'correct' subjects which are on the individual x axis'?

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Custom plot to plot sorted barplot
def sortedplot(x,y, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    data = kwargs.pop("data")
    data.sort_values('value').plot(kind='bar',x=x, y=y, ax=ax,**kwargs)

# testdata of multi indexed random data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,200,size=(100, 2)), 
                    columns=list(('X','Y')))
index = np.array(zip(np.arange(0,201),np.tile(np.array(['A','B','C','D']),25)))
df['subject'] = index.flatten()[0::2]
df['group'] = index.flatten()[1::2]
df = df.set_index(['subject','group'])

# melt the test dataframe
meltdf = pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['subject','group'], var_name='PEAK')
sns.set(font_scale=2)

g = sns.FacetGrid(meltdf,col='group',row='PEAK',sharey=False, size=6, aspect=1.3)
g.map_dataframe(sortedplot, 'subject', 'value')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try `sharex=False`.

Comment: Excellent! I could swear I tried that as one of my first solutions...

Comment: Now why is it that I cannot simply pass `meltdf.sort_values('value')` and use sns.barplot instead of defining my own `sortedplot` function